# What is the max udp length?

Tags: networking, network-programming, udp

what is the max udp length? and how i calculate it?

I read a little bit about that in the internet and figured out that it should be 2^16 - 1 but why it should be calculated like this?

thanks for helping..

Comment: If you look at [the UDP packet header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Packet_structure) you might understand why.

Comment: i understood that but i dont know how they got 65535 maximum bytes of data?

Comment: What is the maximum value a 16-bit unsigned integer can have?